# Can I add a 'wireless only' router off my Verizon Fios router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, fios

I have a Verizon Fios and their MI424WR router (this uses coaxial cable). My main issue is that my wireless signal seems slow and unreliable these days.

I requested a replacement but it doesn't seem to work, that is I unhook up the coax cable but it doesn't connect to the internet (plugging it back to the old router the internet connection works fine so it seems to be the new router).

So I'm thinking about buying a replacement.  But my connection is coaxial and most routers don't have connections for this.  And since my main issue is wireless I'm thinking about getting just hooking up a new router for wireless only (and turning off the wireless on the verizon router)

Questions:

1. Would I run into any issue setting up a 'wireless only' router off the verizon router?
2. Can I somehow convert the coax to ethernet and use a new route as my only router?
3. Would there be any advantage to having only one router?
4. Any thoughts on the replacement router not connecting to the internet.  Am I missing some setup step?  (I wait the 1 to 6 mins for it to configure itself as the documentation says, and eventually I did a hard re-set on router too)

GB

Comment: I would get Verizon to provide the service you are paying them for. If you really cannot wait that long, then you could use another router in AP (access point) mode; or, if you have an Ethernet-connected PC with wireless (in-built or USB dongle), then create a bridge, so that this PC becomes your wireless router; but keep chasing Verizon: they supplied the hardware, so it's their problem to fix it, not yours.

Comment: Ended up contacting Verizon, they had to do something on their end to get the router to be recognized.  Signal strength\speed is backup to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, and not hard to do. I purchased an inexpensive ASUS router, set it up as a LAN device off the Actiontec, shut off it's DCHP and set it up as an access point.No loss of Verizon FIOS material, shut off wireless in the Actiontec, or assign it to "the kids"..